# Last piece priority: playing mp4 incomplete torrents

Tags: python, libtorrent

I need to download the first last piece of a mp4 torrent file so I could play the unfinished file with vlc while it's downloading. There's my code:

```
import libtorrent as lt
import time
import sys

ses = lt.session()
ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)

info = lt.torrent_info(sys.argv[1])
h = ses.add_torrent({'ti': info, 'save_path': './'})
print 'starting', h.name()

while (not h.is_seed()):
   s = h.status()

   state_str = ['queued', 'checking', 'downloading metadata', \
      'downloading', 'finished', 'seeding', 'allocating', 'checking fastresume']
   print '\r%.2f%% complete (down: %.1f kb/s up: %.1f kB/s peers: %d) %s' % \
      (s.progress * 100, s.download_rate / 1000, s.upload_rate / 1000, \
      s.num_peers, state_str[s.state]),
   sys.stdout.flush()

   time.sleep(1)

print h.name(), 'complete'
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to code what I have asked. If someone can help me..

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

```
h.piece_priority(info.num_pieces()-1,7)
```

Source:
[How to download specific files by using python-libtorrent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249113/how-to-download-specific-files-by-using-python-libtorrent)